# How to implement custom header icons within a (nested) StackNavigator?

Tags: react-native

This might be a noobish question, but although I read the documentation and other sources, I still did not figure out **how to implement two or more additional, clickable icons in the header within a StackNavigator**, just like in the picture. If the stackNavigator wants to show a back-icon, he is allowed to overwrite the menu-icon.

This is how the (root) home-screen could look like. Once the user starts clicking on the content, the menu-item should be replaced with the back-button from the stackNavigator (ideally on any platform).
[image: Mockup of what I want to achieve.]

**What I did so far:** I started from a brand-new template by choosing the options `tabs` when running `expo init`. I did some minor modifications in the file **MainTabNavigator.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import CustomHeader from '../components/CustomHeader';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';    

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator( { Home: HomeScreen }, {
   // default config for screens in the stack, so `Home` will use this title 
  navigationOptions: { 
    title: 'Protype Prompter: Browse',
    header: props => <CustomHeader {...props} />,
    }}
);
// All other code stays like provided by expo init.
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
});
```

Next, I made sure that within **HomeScreen.js** the header is not overwritten:

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  /* static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  }; */
```

Please help me to with my **CustomHeader.js**. All my efforts so far so did not lead to any visible change on the home screen.

```
import React from "react";
import { Header } from "react-navigation";
import { View, Platform, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { SimpleLineIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
const CustomHeader = props => {
  return (
    <View>
        <SimpleLineIcons name="menu" size={24} color={tintColor} />
         <Header headerLeft={<SimpleLineIcons name="menu" size={24} color='#6a1b9a' />} {...props} />
    </View>
  );
};
export default CustomHeader;
```

Beside other sources, I consulted so far the following websites:

1. The documentation on [headers](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html) and [header buttons](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/header-buttons.html)
2. A [github discussion on a react-navitation issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1989)
3. A [howto on modifying headers](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html) and another one on [customer headers with react-navigation](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-a-custom-header-and-custom-bottom-tab-bar-for-react-native-with-react-navigation-969a5d3cabb1). The latter seemed to be a good starting point.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is pretty easy actually. Considered you are using React Navigation V2 or V3, take a look at the [`createStackNavigator` docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/2.x/stack-navigator.html#navigationoptions-for-screens-inside-of-the-navigator).

There you have a `headerLeft` and a `headerRight` setting which can both take a custom component. So you can easily code up your example header.

### Edit

So I coded up an example fastly:

In your `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Navigator from "./navigation/navigation";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Navigator />;
  }
}
```

`navigation.js`:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({ HomeScreen });

export default RootStack;
```

Now you can design your header on a screen by screen basis like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-navigation";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  icon: {
    paddingLeft: 10
  },
  iconContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    width: 120
  }
});

export class HomeScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Title",
    headerLeft: (
      <Icon
        containerStyle={styles.icon}
        type="ionicon"
        name={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios-menu" : "md-menu"}
      />
    ),
    headerRight: (
      <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
        <Icon type="ionicon" name={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios-search" : "md-search"} />
        <Icon type="ionicon" name={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios-heart" : "md-heart"} />
        <Icon type="ionicon" name={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios-more" : "md-more"} />
      </View>
    )
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView styles={styles.container}>
        <Text>Hi from the HomeScreen.</Text>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

I used [the `<Icon />` component](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/icon.html) from react-native-elements. You can make these icons clickable by giving them an `onPress` prop.

Here is a screenshot of the result on iOS:

[image]

**Shameless plug:**
If you want to know more about React Navigation [you might like my tutorial](https://medium.com/@jan.hesters/building-a-react-native-app-with-complex-navigation-using-react-navigation-85a479308f52) in which I guide you through building an application with production ready navigation settings.

Comment: I am aware of these, but I do not know where to put it, see my modifications within CustomHeader.js

Comment: @B--rian I'm coding up an example as we speak, give me like fifteen more minutes 

Comment: Hi, I am still curious how to out-source the navigationOptions into my CustomHeader.js.

Comment: @B--rian I think other people tried to answer that. Right now, I don't have the time to code up an example for that, too, since it would take way longer than just using `navigationOptions`. To be honest, I haven't seen a single use case where a `<CustomHeader />` would be needed  What is you goal with the `<CustomHeader />`? The React Navigation API probably already exposes a nice solution and maybe I can help you find it.

Comment: Trying your code, I always receive the error "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'styles.icon')." The error occurs in exactly those lines where you call the style. I did make sure that I am importing everything and have no typo. Any idea?

Comment: @B--rian Could you edit your question and post the code that you used while trying out my code? If not, could you answer whether the other styles work (`container` and `iconContainer`)? Do note that due to [hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) the styles need to be defined in a seperate `styles.js` file, or above the class, since we are accessing the styles in a static property. Other than that you could also try just using inline styles `containerStyle={{paddingLeft: 10}}`.

Comment: The inline styles did actually work! That was exactly the issue.

Comment: @J.Hesters I need a better solution to design a header. I am using stack and tab navigation. But I need to change all subscreens header as different. How can i design which need to applicable for all devices. Refer my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705254/question-how-can-i-design-a-header-which-is-applicable-for-all-devices-in-react

Answer (score 4):

Now in React Navigation version 6.x and React Native version 0.68, you can directly pass `headerLeft` and `headerRight` in your `Stack.Screen`'s `options` prop.

Here's the code example of `headerLeft` function as some Icon in your `Stack.Screen`:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomePage}
  options={{
    headerLeft: (props) => (
      <Pressable
        android_ripple={{
          color: "#666666",
          foreground: true,
          borderless: true,
        }}
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.openDrawer();
        }}
      >
        <Ionicon
          style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
          name={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios-menu" : "md-menu"}
          size={25}
        />
      </Pressable>
    ),
  }}
/>
```

See the result in screenshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let consider if `route.js` like following

```
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import Home from "./home.js";
import Login from "./login.js";

export default Navigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Login: { screen: Login },
});
```

Using [native-base](https://nativebase.io) can create custom header view

```
// CustomHeader.js
import { Header, Left, Right, Body, Thumbnail } from "native-base";
<Header
  style={{
    backgroundColor: "#f8f8f8",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  }}
>
  <Left style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
    <Icon
      name="ios-menu-outline"
      color="#000"
      size={26}
      style={{ paddingLeft: 15, width: 40 }}
      onPress={}
    />
  </Left>
  <Body style={{}}>
    <Text style={{}}>Name</Text>
  </Body>
  <Right>
    <Icon
      name="ios-menu-outline"
      color="#000"
      size={26}
      style={{ paddingLeft: 15, width: 40 }}
      onPress={}
    />
  </Right>
</Header>
```

home.js file like following

for Drawer [Drawer component](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer)

```
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
};
```

under your drawer component can create custom header

```
render(){
  return(
    <Drawer> //Assumed you have some drawer component
        <CustomHeader data={"title"}/>
        <ScrollView>
        </ScrollView>
    </Drawer>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your lines. I am a bit confused since you are using a Drawer-component, I am not (yet) using. In my situation it is a StackNavigator within a TabNavigator, see modified question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the below mentioned code in your class.

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: 'Home Page',
    headerRight: (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.7}
            onPress={() => { params.logoutClick() }}>
            <Text style={navItemTxt}> Logout</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity >
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.7}
            onPress={() => { params.clearCartClick() }}>
            <Image source={require('../images/search/ic_clear_cart.png')}
                style={navItemImg} />
        </TouchableOpacity >
        <ConnectedBadgeTitle navigation={navigation} badgeAction={() => { navigation.navigate('Cart'); }} />
    </View >
    ),
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise example. Where exactly should I put these navigationOptions? Ideally, I would like to have the whole configuration of "headerRight" within CustomHeader.js

Comment: Put it in your HomeScreen class.

Comment: I actually had to put it into MainTabNavigation.js into the createStackNavigator.