# Question: How can I design a header which is applicable for all devices in react-native

Tags: header, material-ui, react-native, react-native-ios

I need to design a header like below-attached image. Can I able to design this using react-native elements or material-ui.

Here the profile name may be the lengthiest name or short name. But needs to work and start from that place.

Can anyone suggest a good solution?

Note: I have used react-native-elements (Header) but it not worked for me as expected

[image]

Comment: You can use `react navigation` header

Comment: I am using react-navigation header in all  stacknavigation screens. So the same will reflect in subscreens. I have nulled the header for subscreens because i not need the same header of main screen in the subscreens. Can u elaborate your answer with any refernce

Answer (score 0):

You can design completely custom Header with React navigation. By setting header height in `navigationOptions`

```javascript
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  Image
} from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

const commonHeader = (navigation) => ({
  headerLeft: null,
  headerRight: null,
  headerStyle: { 
    backgroundColor: '#4DBCD7',
    height: 180,
  },
  headerTitle: (
    <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingHorizontal: 15 }}>
        <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            {/* upper left portion with back icon */}
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            {/* upper right portion with other icons */}
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 2, alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'space-around', paddingHorizontal: 50, paddingVertical: 10 }}>
          {/* lower portion with image & username */}
      </View>
    </View>
  )
});

export default createStackNavigator({ 
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions:  ({ navigation }) => commonHeader(navigation)
  }
});
```

Then, you can use this `commonHeader` anywhere you want...

---

**EDIT**
(For dynamic header content)

To set header content dynamically, you can make a separate `Header` component and then set your dynamic content using `props`

*Header.js*

```javascript
...
export default Header = props => {
  const { left, right, children } = props;

  return (
    <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingHorizontal: 15 }}>
        {left}

        {right}
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 2, paddingHorizontal: 50, paddingVertical: 10 }}>
        {children}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Then in your *StackNavigator*

```javascript
export default createStackNavigator({ 
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerLeft: null,
      headerRight: null,
      headerStyle: { 
        backgroundColor: '#4DBCD7',
        height: 180,
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Then set your dynamic content in respective screen. e.g. *HomeScreen*

```javascript
...
import Header from 'Header';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: (
      <Header navigation={navigation}
      left={
         /* left content (back icon) */
      }
      right={
         /* right (other icons) */
      }>
          {/* main content (image, text, etc.) */}
      </Header>
    )
  }

  ...
}
```

This is the final result. Hope it'll help you as well!
[image]

Comment: Yes, But I have a different screens and different methods for delete, edit and back. So If I use all the above in react-navigation routes.js file then I can't able to perform different actions in a different screen. The above is correct If I use same actions in all screens. Did you know any other options

Comment: You mean, you need dynamic content in left (back), right (other icons) & main (image & text) part of headers???

Comment: Yes, correct. Here  left (back), right (other icons) & main (image & text) are same place in all subscreens. But the methods for each one is differ

Comment: I've edited my answer to cater your need of dynamic header content. You can use separate header component and set dynamic items using props

Comment: Also, I have a question. If I need to add the header left and right is icon as well as text. If I add text in header title then it shows invariant violation of <Text> in a </View> as shows an error. Can you tell I f I need to use (left or right) both text and image means what will be your suggestion?

Comment: This is my code in my screen. The left and right may be a text or image icons in some screens. navigation is not known in this screen. Why? Can u tell me where is the wrong in my code? 
      <HeaderBar navigation={navigation}>
      left={
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity = { .5 } onPress={() => this.goBack()}>
                  <Entypo name = {'chevron-thin-left'} size ={27} style = {styles.leftComponentHeader}></Entypo>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      }
      right={<Text style={{fontSize:30, color:'white'}}>Title of my user name</Text>}>
      </HeaderBar>

Comment: what's the error are you getting, Can you show it clearly in your edited question?

Comment: I got solution in react-native-elements